# How to remove blank space after string

Tags: php

I am trying to remove string from a .txt file in PHP, and when I do that it leaves blank space. What I tried:

```
$content = file_get_contents('../admin/accounts.txt');
$content = str_replace('line3', '', $content);
file_put_contents('../admin/accounts.txt', $content);
```

File before edit:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

File after edit:

```
line1
line2

line4
line5
```

I want to remove that exact whitespace and file to look like:

```
line1
line2
line4
line5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What actually is going on is that when you are seeing a file shaped as following:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

it actually is something like the following:

```
line1\n
line2\n
line3\n
line4\n
line5
```

Personally speaking, I highly prefer using `regex` and therefore, `preg_replace` instead of `str_replace` to overcome this problem. The code I came up with is:

```
$content = file_get_contents('../admin/accounts.txt');
$replaceString = preg_replace("/line3([\s\r\n]+)?/m", "", $content);
echo $replaceString;
```

So even if the `accounts.txt` has the following content this code would work fine!

### Input(accounts.txt)

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line3 line3
line3
line12
```

### Output by the code

```
line1
line2
line4
line5
line12
```

Comment: Please explain why there is an `m` modifier in your pattern.  Also, `[\s\r\n]` is the same as `\s`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line including the newline character. Try first with "\n":

```
$content = str_replace("line3\n", '', $content);   // note the double quotes around _line3\n_
```

Note that this will not work if there is whitespace between line3 and \n.

Also note that this will not work when removing the last line and there is not "\n" following.

Regex would also work (including the elimination of 'line5'):

```
$content = "
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
";

$search = 'line3';

$result = preg_replace("/($search)([ \t]*)(\R?)/i", '', $content);

print_r($result);

// (line3)  -> matches the 'line3' (case-insensitive, see the /i at the end)
// ([ \t]*) -> matches spaces and/or tabs, zweo to unlimited times
// (\R?)    -> matches any newline character or sequence zero or one times
```

Comment: Why are there capture groups if you aren't using them in the replacement?

Comment: Readability. The alternatives are: _"/($search)(?:[ \t]*)(?:\R?)/i"_ and _"/($search)[ \t]*\R?/i"_, which I both find less readable.

Comment: And [`/$search\h*\R?/i`](https://3v4l.org/X6iSi) ...which is dead simple to read because there is no unnecessary syntax bloating the pattern.